# binding multiple react components from the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just got started in React and am confused about something.  Let's say I have a Login controller view (smart component), and then a LoginForm view (dumb component), and within the LoginForm, I created custom components for  to handle all my inputs on this page the same.

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <input type="text"
          name={this.props.name}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          ref={this.props.name}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          value={this.props.value} />
    );
  }
}

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
      name="username"
      placeholder="Username"
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
      value={this.props.username} />
      <TextInput
      name="address"
      placeholder="Address"
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
      value={this.props.address} />
     );
   }
}
```

I'm then not sure how in my top level Login controller view's render function, when I create the

How do you get a different to be called for the different inputs?  Because my top level component sets the properties down right?  Since the bottom most component expects an onChange property, from the top level when I pass down onChange, aren't all TextInputs going to call the same onChange method instead of two separate methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the same function is called.  What changes is the parameter.  This is just old school JS.  The `input` will pass the change event to to the onChange function as the first param.

You will need to handle that in one component or another.

```
onChange(e){
    var formKeyVal = {};
    formKeyVal[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(formKeyVal); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `refs` We can set up different referring to each low-level element. No matter, dumb or smart.
Your high-level component contains:

```
`handleText(){
            this.setState({
                text: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.yourElement).value
            })
        }`
```

Your low-level component contains:
            `<input 
                        type="text"
                        ref="yourElement"
                        onChange={this.props.textInput}
                        />`

This example gives you some clue. Pay attention to details: Selector: `refs` 
but element: `ref`.
From time to time you need two level `refs`. In this case it would be 
 `text: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.yourComponent.refs.yourElement).value`